# Emacs recent buffers use `~` abbreviation?

Tags: spacemacs, buffers, ivy

I have my entire Spacemacs config syncing between a Mac and a Linux machine, which provides a lot of benefits. My packages are always up to date on both systems, a configuration change on one machine updates the other, etc.

However I'm having a problem where my recent buffer list (`ivy-switch-buffer`) is saving the *absolute paths* of my recently opened files. This means that if I open a file on Linux `~/notes.org`, it stores `/home/mwaldrich/notes.org`. Then when I try to switch to this buffer on my Mac, it points to the wrong path since macOS uses `/Users/mwaldrich/notes.org`.

**Is there any way to force Emacs to record recent buffers with paths relative to my home directory?**

I have already tried to symlink `/home/` to `/Users/` on macOS, but this is a temporary fix and doesn't fully solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is controlled by the variable  recentf-filename-handlers
This tells recentf how to handle the files after processing.

I have `(setq recentf-filename-handlers '(abbreviate-file-name))` in my init file (it also can be changed by customization) and my recentf-list contains ~ . This is the variable saved and set in the file that persists recentf

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! How did you find out about this?

Comment: This did take me time and I can't remeber tyhe exact but it would have included looking at all the possible customizattion variable e.g. `M-x customize-group` and respond with recentf